# How to resolve time zone offset issue for dates in ASP.net core and Angular?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.net core 5 and angular 15.0 for backend and frontend respectively. When a date property is got from the user on the client side (e.g.  Sun Jan 01 2023 21:27:11 GMT+0330 (XXX Standard Time)), before posting it to the server as an object, it is converted to ISO format (i.e. it is converted to : 2023-01-01T17:57:11.528Z) and sent to the server as an object to save in database. When retrieving the same date from the server, it will be displayed one day earlier. The OffsetZone is -210 (-3:30'). How to add the time offset to the received Date property by controller action (i.e. Received Date property is converted to 2023-01-01T21:27:11, Be exactly the same as the local Date value) in the action before it is saved to the database? best regards

Comment: Sachin Dilshan's answer is feasible. The reason for this problem may be that the backend server is not in the same time zone as the accessed browser. You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript), it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We standardised our comms between front and back end a while ago.

The main point being the same as you are already doing - sending/receiving the dates in UTC ISO format. Doing this gives you a clear, shared based for each to work on as desired.

The second part is to use `DateTimeOffset` in our models instead of the more basic `DateTime`.

This parses the ISO string, just like `DateTime` does, but gives you accessor options for `x.LocalDateTime` to have it pull out a `DateTime` value according to the server's local time (which it sounds like what you want) as well as retrieving the base UTC time for it with `x.UtcDateTime` if you so desire.

E.g.

```
public class SomeInput {
    [Required]
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset TheTime { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class SomeController : ... {
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<IActionResult> SomeAction(SomeInput input) {
        var utc = input.TheTime.UtcDateTime;
        var serverLocal = input.TimeTime.LocalDateTime;

        // ...
    }
}
```

In this way, you can make sure you pass through the `serverLocal` value rather than the UTC value to your services so it's all working on your server's local time.

Comment: Thank you. I spent a lot of time on this issue. You provided a very good solution.